# Do I need to pay tax of my stock earning in the US if my income is low?

Tags: united-states, taxes, stocks

Assume I do not have income and I have 1 million dollars worth of stock. 99.9% earned from market.

Do I need pay tax if I sell $1000 per month at USA?

Comment: If these are long-term capital gains, [maybe not](https://www.thebalance.com/how-to-use-the-zero-percent-tax-rate-on-capital-gains-2388995)?

Answer (score 6):

The short answer: if you only have long-term capital gains and dividends and no other income, and you're selling only $1,000 per month, then you should owe no federal income taxes on it. You could owe state income taxes on it, though, depending on the state.

**Federal**

Federal tax law has an interesting feature. In 2017, if your taxable income was below $37,950 (single) or $75,900 (married), then your dividends and capital gains were taxed at 0%. The relevant place to look is on line 8 of the "Qualified Dividends and Capital Gain Tax Worksheet", which is on page 44 of the [2017 1040 instructions](https://www.irs.gov/pub/irs-pdf/i1040gi.pdf).

Note that you can make less than $75,900 in dividends and they will still be taxed if you have high enough ordinary income. So if you are married and have a salary of $75,900 and you have just $1 of dividend income, that $1 will be taxed.

Also note that since you would have also had deductions and exemptions, a married couple could have made much more than $75,900 in dividends and still kept their taxable income below the threshold.

Finally, note that there was a large overhaul to the tax code which takes effect in 2018. Of course I don't have the 2018 1040 yet, but this feature should not have changed in its essence, though the numbers have changed. According to [this web site](https://www.corporatemonkeycpa.com/2018/02/22/taxes-on-dividends-and-capital-gains-under-the-tax-cuts-jobs-act/), the new thresholds are $38,600 (single) and $77,200 (married).

**State**

Every state is different. Some states have no income tax at all, and according to the [Tax Foundation](https://taxfoundation.org/how-high-are-personal-dividends-income-tax-rates-your-state/), most states tax dividends as ordinary income. So you likely will pay state income tax on your investment income.

Of course, as I'm not a tax professional or anything, please sprinkle "it's my understanding that..." across all the appropriate places above.